# webdatarocks through a excetion with Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ua'), when call dataRocks.webdatarocks.googlecharts.getData

Tags: vue.js, webdatarocks

when call method webdatarocks.googlecharts.getData();

it through exception like:
webdatarocks.js:182 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'ua'

But the other webdatarocks component on the same page is normal.

Comment: Could you share a code sample of how you are handling the multiple wdr components?